# Python DataFrame ExcelWriter, returns an error

Tags: python, dataframe, nameerror

I am trying to over-write specific tabs in an excel file (leaving the rest intact). I am trying to copy synatx from the documentation but I get an error.

```
with ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\Tiki\Desktop\work\VFT Technicals\Production2\dashboard_v2.xlsx') as writer: 
    output_rsi.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='rsi')
```

This returns the error:

```
NameError: name 'ExcelWriter' is not defined
```

Hoping for some advice, I am very much a beginner at coding.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your script is not recognize `'ExcelWriter'` keyword.
it is part of python's pandas library.
you should write below things to work it out.

please try :

`import pandas as pd`
and use

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\Tiki\Desktop\work\VFT Technicals\Production2\dashboard_v2.xlsx') as writer: 
    output_rsi.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='rsi')
```

or
`import pandas.ExcelWriter as ExcelWriter`

Comment: Dead on! It was a typo I was making. Thank you very much.